# Boost Shared Memory

Tags: c++, memory, boost, shared

I'm trying to get a shared char Array between to Applications with the help of boost's windows_shared_memory.

```
void testApp::initSharedMem()
{
  using namespace boost::interprocess;

  //Create a native windows shared memory object.
  windows_shared_memory shm (create_only, "MySharedMemory", read_write, 256);

  //Map the whole shared memory in this process
  mapped_region region(shm, read_write);

  //Write all the memory to 1
  std::memset(region.get_address(), 'a', 256 * sizeof(char));
  beatLines = static_cast<char*>(region.get_address());

  beatLines[10] = 'b';
}
```

The last line `beatLines[10] = 'b';` works perfectly but when i try to assign one of the vars of the beatLines Array outside of the initSharedMem() Method (but in the same class)
I get a  Access violation writing Exception.

Comment: Showing us the code that does work doesn't help as much as showing us the code that doesn't work.

Comment: shouldn't `shm`, `region` and `beatLines` be attributes of `testApp`? (RAII principle)